# Varchar to datetime in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, substring

I'm trying to capture the datepart from an filename and trying to convert it to datetime datatype.

```
SELECT CONVERT(Datetime, substring('EmployeeExcel_03312013',15,22), 120)
```

Getting below error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Any ideas? Please suggest if I am missing anything?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following:

```
SELECT 
  convert(datetime, 
           right('EmployeeExcel_03312013', 4)
            +substring('EmployeeExcel_03312013',15,4), 112)
```

This get the value in the format `20130331` before the being converted to a date.

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68b32/117)

Answer (score 1):

You can give this a go

```
DECLARE @Date char(8)
set @Date=substring('EmployeeExcel_03312013',15,22)
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,RIGHT(@Date,4)+LEFT(@Date,2)+SUBSTRING(@Date,3,2))
```

Output:

```
-----------------------
2013-03-31 00:00:00.000

(1 row(s) affected)
```

[SQLFiddle Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/3350)

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar post on here: [Convert varchar into datetime in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509977/convert-varchar-into-datetime-in-sql-server)

To make it more simple:

```
select convert(datetime, '03312013', 120) --produces error
```

This indicates that CONVERT doesn't know what to do with a string formatted that way.

If you split up the date to look more like '03-31-2013' (which is what the link above indicates) or something similar you'll be good.