# How to convert varchar to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working in SQL Server 2008 R2

I need to convert a varchar(50) field in a view to a date format.

I have a view that uses the following to create the field delivered_date:

```
convert(varchar(50),[delvd_dt],110) as [delivered_date]
```

The formatted field looks like : 2012-03-11 16:24:42.0000000

I need the results to be a date so that I can check for dates within a range.  I would prefer to do it within the view so that I can use SSRS to create the range for the report.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert varchar into datetime in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509977/convert-varchar-into-datetime-in-sql-server)

Comment: Well, why don't you FIX the table and store it in the right data type in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `cast()`?  The following returns the right date for me:

```
select CAST('2012-03-11 16:24:42.0000000' as DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can simply truncate the millis and use `CONVERT`:

```
SELECT Convert(datetime, LEFT('2012-03-11 16:24:42.0000000', 19), 102) AS [Date]
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/12822/0)

This works even in MS SQL-Server 2005.

[**CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Answer (score -3):

Try this [link](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx) website shows several formatting options.

Example:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 105)
```

Comment: Goes the wrong direction. He already has a character, wants to get a datetime.

Comment: The confusing part of the quote is the word "format". He's saying he already has a varchar(50), and he wants a date of some kind. Replace "format" with "type" and it makes more sense.