# Conversion failed converting to datetime from character string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, datetime

I tried the below sample Function ... and i tried in many other ways but still i am getting the Error as "Conversion failed when converting Datetime from character string".. All i am trying is from this function i am returning a Datetime but somewhere here its still string ...

Please advise

```
declare  @V_Year nvarchar (4), @Test datetime , @t1 as datetime  , @t2 as datetime 
declare @Mon varchar(5) , @dayz varchar (5) , @GMTStart varchar(20)
set @Mon = '03' 
set @t1  = cast ( @Mon as datetime)
set @dayz = '01'
set @t2  = cast ( @dayz as datetime)
SELECT @V_Year =  DATEPART(year, getdate())
set @GMTStart  = @Mon + '-' + @dayz + '-' + convert(nvarchar,@V_Year)
set @Test = Cast(@GMTStart as datetime)
select @Test
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert varchar into datetime in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509977/convert-varchar-into-datetime-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your code a bit:

```
declare  
    @V_Year nvarchar (4), 
    @Test datetime , 
    @t1 as datetime , 
    @t2 as datetime 
declare 
    @Mon varchar(8), --here need to be varchar(8) because datetime has 8 digits
    @dayz varchar(5), 
    @GMTStart varchar(20)
set @Mon = '20130101' --here you must provide full date, not a part, because is not possible to convert just part of date into full date
set @t1  = cast (@Mon as datetime) --this will work with 
--set @dayz = '01'
--set @t2  = cast (@dayz as datetime) --this line not work with just day, must provide full date

SET @V_Year =  DATEPART(year, getdate()) --here first set a variable, and then select
SELECT @V_Year
set @GMTStart  = @Mon + '-' + @dayz + '-' + convert(nvarchar, @V_Year)
set @Test = Cast(@GMTStart as datetime)
select @Test
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is creating a datetime value of March 3 in the current year.

The interpretation of date strings is dependent on `set dateformat` unless you use the format `yyyymmdd`.

Removing all the stuff from your code that does not seem to do anything useful will leave you with this.

```
select cast(cast(year(getdate()) as char(4))+'0301' as datetime)
```