# Converting varchar(50) to datetime data type in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqldatatypes

I'm trying to update varchar(50) field to datetime in SQL Server, tried couple of ways but no success.

I ways get error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

Here is sample values in the OrderDateTime column:

```
2014-05-21 04:21:45.3346898
2014-02-26 08:43:58.5693805
2014-04-29 15:57:21.0778236
2014-04-09 07:23:57.3886545
2014-03-14 16:03:46.3919145
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Please help me either to identify that row causing issue or let me know if any force convert to datetime way available.

I tried these:

```
UPDATE  Orders SET OrderDateTime=CONVERT(datetime, OrderDateTime)
UPDATE  Orders SET OrderDateTime=CAST(OrderDateTime AS datetime)
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509977/convert-varchar-into-datetime-in-sql-server ??

Comment: did you check with my answer ? let me know if you have still problems

Comment: I think @Arunprasanth KV's answer should work! too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE  Orders SET OrderDateTime=CAST(OrderDateTime AS datetime2)
```

**Note** :if you're on `SQL Server 2008` or newer, you could use the `DATETIME2` datatype instead of plain `DATETIME`.

> `datetime2` can be considered as an extension of the existing `datetime` type that has a larger date range, a larger default fractional precision, and optional user-specified precision.

Comment: great.. worked, but not sure my application will complain if I use datetime2, let me know your experience?

Comment: @AVatsa you can use that , just see the updated answer, it is just an extension of datetime

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
ODBC canonical (with milliseconds).
------------------------------------

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-05-04 14:14:35.073', 21)

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-05-04 14:14:35.073', 121)

ISO8601.
--------
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-05-04T14:14:35.073', 126) -- 2013-05-04 14:14:35.073 

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 127) -- 2013-05-04T14:14:35.073
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-05-04T14:14:35.073', 127) -- 2013-05-04 14:14:35.073
```

**Reference Url:**
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/576178/cast-convert-format-try-parse-date-and-time-sql#2_3