# Convert Varchar containing date to DATETIME

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with 6k+ rows and don't want to have to manually convert each date to DATETIME, they are currently in varchar.

They are in the UK format, DD/MM/YYYY.

Currently the date is in a column named *datetime* which is varchar(12)

I want to convert it to a datetime column named *date_new*.

How can I do this using an SQL statement

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert varchar into datetime in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509977/convert-varchar-into-datetime-in-sql-server)

Comment: in mysql, use function `STR_TO_DATE(datetime,'%d/%m/%Y')`.   usually these strings would be stored in a varchar(10)..

Comment: @amdixon Thanks, I managed to perform an update using this function. Problem Solved :)

Comment: @RichardErickson Not a duplicate because linked topic refers to MsSql and this one to MySql.

Answer (score 1):

Solved using

```
UPDATE table SET date_test = STR_TO_DATE( DATETIME,  '%d/%m/%Y' )
```