# How to Convert nvarchar (including time) into datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data 20160526094432, and I want to convert into datetime in SQLServer
The result will be 2016-05-26 09:44:32

Is there simple way to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: By handy to know the name of the database that you are using

Comment: possible duplicate [Convert varchar into datetime in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509977/convert-varchar-into-datetime-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use MS SQL Server 2012 or newer then you can enjoy `format` function.

```
select cast(format(20160526094432,'####-##-## ##:##:##') as datetime) [date-time]
```

If your long number is a string then you have to convert it.

```
declare @d varchar(20)='20160526094432'
select cast(format(cast(@d as bigint),'####-##-## ##:##:##') as datetime) [date-time]
```

Comment: I am using SQLServer 2014, I want to update my table.
update copy_vw_work_in_progress_so_list
Set picking_datetime = CAST(FORMAT([picking_date],'####-##-## ##:##:##') as datetime).

and error Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Argument data type nvarchar is invalid for argument 1 of format function.

Comment: See my update. `...CAST(FORMAT(cast([picking_date] as bigint),'####-##-## ##:##:##') as datetime)...`

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  I don't think there is a *really* clean way, but something like this should work:

```
select (convert(datetime, left(col, 8) as datetime) +
        convert(datetime, convert(time,
                                  stuff(stuff(right(col, 6), 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':')
                                 )
                )
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try in this way, for example Date is the column of your table, 103 is the format of Date you want to convert, google for more details.

```
CONVERT(datetime, Date, 103)
```

Comment: I've already tried but get error
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.