# SQL Row_Number() not sorting dates

Tags: sql

I have a query in which I am trying to get the most recent date from my `ROW_NUMBER()` selection. I have tried both `MAX()` and `DESC` in my `ORDER BY` clause. It does not show the most recent date as `RowNum 1`.

This is my query:

```
;WITH cte3 AS
(       
    SELECT
        o.PartNo, 
        o.JobNo,
        MAX(tt.TicketDate) as rawr,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY o.JobNo, o.PartNo 
                           ORDER BY tt.TicketDate DESC) as RowNum    
    FROM
        OrderDet AS o    
    INNER JOIN 
        TimeTicketDet AS tt ON o.JobNo = tt.JobNo       
    WHERE
        o.Status = 'Open'
    GROUP BY
        tt.TicketDate, o.JobNo, o.PartNo
)    
SELECT *
FROM cte3
```

When I get it giving me the correct results, I will add a `WHERE RowNum = 1` in the cte query.

With my current query, this is the result:

```
+--------+-------+-----------+--------+
| PartNo | JobNo |   rawr    | RowNum |
+--------+-------+-----------+--------+
|   1234 |    20 | 5/30/2012 |      1 |
|   1234 |    20 | 5/29/2012 |      2 |
|   1234 |    20 | 5/25/2012 |      3 |
|   1234 |    20 | 5/24/2012 |      4 |
|   1234 |    20 | 5/23/2012 |      5 |
|   1234 |    20 | 5/22/2012 |      6 |
|   1234 |    20 | 5/16/2012 |      7 |
|   1234 |    20 | 5/15/2012 |      8 |
|   1234 |    20 | 5/14/2012 |      9 |
|   1234 |    20 | 5/11/2012 |     10 |
|   1234 |    20 | 5/10/2012 |     11 |
|   1234 |    20 | 5/9/2012  |     12 |
|   1234 |    20 | 3/27/2015 |     13 |
|   1234 |    20 | 1/3/2013  |     14 |
|   1234 |    20 | 1/2/2013  |     15 |
+--------+-------+-----------+--------+
```

`RowNum = 13` is the most recent date. Am I organizing my sorts incorrectly or incorrectly converting my dates?

**EDIT:**

**TimeTicketDet Table Sample Data:**

```
+------------+-------+
| TicketDate | JobNo |
+------------+-------+
| 5/9/2012   |    20 |
| 5/10/2012  |    20 |
| 5/24/2012  |    20 |
| 3/27/2015  |    20 |
| 5/22/2012  |    20 |
| 5/10/2012  |    20 |
| 5/11/2012  |    20 |
| 5/9/2012   |   100 |
| 5/10/2012  |   100 |
| 5/24/2012  |   100 |
| 3/27/2015  |   100 |
| 5/22/2012  |   100 |
| 5/10/2012  |   100 |
| 5/11/2012  |   100 |
+------------+-------+
```

**OrderDet Table Sample Data:**

```
+--------+--------+-------+
| PartNo | Status | JobNo |
+--------+--------+-------+
|   1234 | Open   |    20 |
|   1234 | Open   |   100 |
+--------+--------+-------+
```

**Desired Result:**

```
+--------+------------+-------+--------+
| PartNo | TicketDate | JobNo | RowNum |
+--------+------------+-------+--------+
|   1234 | 3/27/2015  |    20 |      1 |
|   1234 | 3/27/2015  |   100 |      1 |
+--------+------------+-------+--------+
```

Comment: What is the datatype on the `TicketDate` column? Could it be a string/varchar?  It doesn't look like a datetime based on the sort.

Comment: Looks Like your `Group By` shouldn't have `tt.TicketDate` in it.  Try it without that.

Comment: When I use row_number for something like this, I dont use group by or aggregates.

I just have where RowNum = 1

Comment: What is your desire result?

Comment: @ollie its a char(8) variable. Is that a string? And if so, can I properly convert that to a date for sorting?

Comment: @RBCKyleBullard Yes, you can [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1510131/426671) or [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/129854/how-to-convert-this-varchar-to-datetime-format). You'll want to convert it in order to get the correct sorting of your dates

Comment: Yes, That is a string. You should store date using date data type. Or use ansi format `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza RowNum 13 to be sorted as RowNum 1 so I can call WHERE RowNum = 1 and get the most recent date.

Comment: Well you also are using a `GROUP BY`  and you shouldnt. Provide the original data and the desire output so we can help you build the correct query.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza is there a way to convert it from a string for the result I am looking for? This is not my database I was just asked to write a few queries on it and I am learning on the fly about how it is setup and honestly how to write queries correctly.

Comment: But that doesn't looks like is sort by string neither, so we need the original CREATE TABLE to be sure what is going on.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza added sample data and desired result to edit. I will check out the link you just sent over. Thanks for all of your help so far by the way.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza it has been updated, sorry, trying to work too fast to get the info you need.

Comment: Please tell me if this is the exact result you are having in your system? http://rextester.com/UUM93496 because as you can see `5/9/2012` should on the top and in your sample output isnt there. So I guess you have several issues together.

Comment: Very similar yes, I truncated (possibly two different ways before and after the edit) the sample data as I get about 100 rows as there are many TicketDates for each JobNo in the actual db. My sample output has it a RowNum 12. I need 3/27/2015 to be the RowNum 1 output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43855943/sql-row-number-not-sorting-dates/43856455#comment74747809_43855943), since your `TicketDate` column is a char, you need to [convert it](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/129854/how-to-convert-this-varchar-to-datetime-format) to a `datetime` in order to sort it by actual date. Right now, you are sorting it by string value which isn't correct.

I'd recommend changing your query to something like this:

```
;WITH cte3 AS
(       
    SELECT
        o.PartNo, 
        o.JobNo,
        MAX(tt.TicketDate) as rawr,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY o.JobNo, o.PartNo 
                           ORDER BY cast(tt.TicketDate as datetime) DESC) as RowNum    
    FROM
        OrderDet AS o    
    INNER JOIN 
        TimeTicketDet AS tt ON o.JobNo = tt.JobNo       
    WHERE
        o.Status = 'Open'
    GROUP BY
        cast(tt.TicketDate as datetime), o.JobNo, o.PartNo
)    
SELECT *
FROM cte3
where RowNum = 1;
```

Here is a [demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/668385).  By casting your `char` to a `datetime` in your `row_number` you will be sorting the data by date instead of string.

Additionally, you don't really need the `max()` and the `GROUP BY` since by casting the `TicketDate` to a datetime you will return the correct row:

```
;WITH cte3 AS
(       
    SELECT
        o.PartNo, 
        o.JobNo,
        tt.TicketDate as rawr,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY o.JobNo, o.PartNo 
                           ORDER BY cast(tt.TicketDate as datetime) DESC) as RowNum    
    FROM
        #OrderDet AS o    
    INNER JOIN 
        #TimeTicketDet AS tt ON o.JobNo = tt.JobNo       
    WHERE
        o.Status = 'Open'
)    
SELECT *
FROM cte3
where RowNum =1;
```

Comment: Dont you need add the cast for `MAX( cast(tt.TicketDate as datetime) )`too ?

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you! I will keep a better lookout in this DB for weird things like strings as dates and whatnot. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza You're correct, I was actually in the process of adding that to my answer

Comment: @ollie I noticed that before and added it before I ran the query on my end.

Answer (score 1):

As Ollie suggest you can `CAST` your string to `DATETIME` And you dont need the additional `Group By`

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/URZFS81823)**

```
;WITH cte3 AS
(       
    SELECT
        o.PartNo, 
        o.JobNo,
        tt.TicketDate as rawr,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY o.JobNo, o.PartNo 
                           ORDER BY cast(tt.TicketDate as datetime) DESC) as RowNum    
    FROM  OrderDet AS o    
    JOIN  TimeTicketDet AS tt 
      ON o.JobNo = tt.JobNo       
    WHERE
        o.Status = 'Open'
)    
SELECT *
FROM cte3
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for all of your help and following up with every comment.