# Row_Number Query for Groupby

Tags: excel, vba

My query is about to get row number as SN in  a SQL query from access database in which I get total sales for the day group by [bill Date] clause

my Working Query is:

```
sql = "SELECT [Bill Date] as [Date], Sum(Purchase) + Sum(Returns) as [Total Sales] FROM TableName Group By [Bill Date];"
```

I found this Row_Number Clause over Internet and i tried like this.

```
sql = "SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Bill Date]) AS [SN], [Bill Date] as [Date], Sum(Purchase) + Sum(Returns) as [Total Sales] FROM TableName Group By [Bill Date];"
```

when i Run the about Code i get this error.

> -2147217900 Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Bill Date]);"

i am using Excel Vba to connect to Access Database 
Could any one help me to to get it in correct order.

Comment: Only see the microsoft examples, always defined ASC or DESC: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Row\_Number() not sorting dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43855943/sql-row-number-not-sorting-dates)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you aren't define **DESC** or **ASC** on `(ORDER BY [Bill Date])`, need be something like this `(ORDER BY [Bill Date] DESC)` or `(ORDER BY [Bill Date] ASC)`

Comment: Same Error, no improvement.

Comment: The problem can be too, the ORDER BY datetime, idk if can make order of datetime. An solution can be the correct answer post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43855943/sql-row-number-not-sorting-dates/43856455