# Convert a Varchar/String with day name to Date in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, casting, sql-server-2014

I have a string `Sunday, November 19, 2017` in Varchar.

How can I convert this to Date Format - `dddd, MMMM, yyyy`?

Comment: what have you tried so far? post your code there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert varchar into datetime in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509977/convert-varchar-into-datetime-in-sql-server)

Comment: @sumitchauhan I don't see the answer to OP's question in this linked question, not with this 'long' date format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this:

```
DECLARE @MyDate VARCHAR(32) = 'Sunday, November 19, 2017';

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), CAST(SUBSTRING(@MyDate, CHARINDEX(',', @MyDate) + 2, 32) AS DATETIME2), 105);  -- 19-11-2017
```

or this:

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST(SUBSTRING(@MyDate, CHARINDEX(',', @MyDate) + 2, 32) AS DATETIME2), 'dddd, MMMM, yyyy'); -- Sunday, November, 2017
```

Comment: Thanks.. It worked for me. 
To get the desired result, did a minor change in the script.
SELECT FORMAT(CAST(SUBSTRING(@MyDate, CHARINDEX(',', @MyDate) + 2, 32) AS DATETIME2), 'dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy'); -- Sunday, November 12, 2017